# .NET: how to write a struct into a file stream?

Tags: .net, struct, f#, stream, binary-data

Here is the definition of `struct MyHeader` in F#

```ml
open System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[<Struct; StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)>]
type MyHeader =
    val mutable Timestamp : uint32
    val mutable Size : uint16
```

which should be equivalent to the below C struct

```c
struct __attribute__((packed)) MyHeader {
    uint32_t Timestamp;
    uint16_t Size;
};
```

There is a very convenient helper class [`MemoryMappedViewAccessor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedviewaccessor.aspx) which works as a "view" of [`MemoryMappedFile`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorymappedfiles.memorymappedfile.aspx) and whose generic method [`Read(T)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd294202.aspx) takes care of everything about reading data into each member of my struct, provided that I specify a correct "offset" within the memory mapped file.  Though what I really want is stream-like operations like below instead of random access,

```cpp
std::ifstream ifs("infile.dat", std::ios::binary);
MyHeader hdr;
while (ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&hdr), sizeof hdr)) {
    char payload[hdr.Size];
    ifs.read(payload, hdr.Size);
    ...
}
```

I can easily emulate them by a simple loop;

```ml
use mmf = System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.MemoryMappedFile.CreateFromFile("infile.dat", System.IO.FileMode.Open)
use view = mmf.CreateViewAccessor()

let loop offset =
    if offset < view.Capacity then
        let hdr = MyHeader()
        view.Read(offset, &hdr)
        let payload = Array.create hdr.Size 0y
        view.ReadArray(offset + sizeof<MyHeader>, payload, 0, hdr.Size)
        ...
        loop <| offset + sizeof<MyHeader> + hdr.Size
    else
        ()

loop 0L
```

However I can't do the same for writing my struct to a binary stream.  The `Write(T)` method of `MemoryMappedViewAccessor` isn't very helpful for me, since it assumes I already have a large enough backend file;  in other words, it is not for extending the output file chunk by chunk.  How can I achieve something like below in F# / .NET?

```cpp
std::ifstream ifs("infile.dat", std::ios::binary);
std::ofstream ofs("outfile.dat", std::ios::binary);
MyHeader hdr;
while (ifs.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&hdr), sizeof hdr)) {
    char payload[hdr.Size];
    ifs.read(payload, hdr.Size);
    ... // modify hdr and payload
    ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char *>(&hdr), sizeof hdr);
    ofs.write(payload, hdr.Size);
}
```

It would be great if I don't need a large in-memory buffer such as [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.aspx).  But my data files are less than 1GB, so it's OK for my purpose to read the entire file into memory.  Moreover, I don't have to use mmap if there's a better way.

Note: I use F# 3.0 / Mono 2.10 on Ubuntu 12.04

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does [this](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a0569495-9fe3-4ac7-bcfa-217eb0ae653a/writing-contents-of-a-struct-using-binarywriter) help? Essentially use types `Marshal` and `GCHandle` to copy the object to a pinned byte buffer, which can then be written to a `BinaryStream`.

Comment: I'm not sure if the method in your provided link is really compatible with .NET `struct` types rather than `object` types... But I somehow got a working code.  Will update later after some checks.

Comment: All struct types can be boxed to create a object reference (this will be done silently by the compiler) or such a method could be made generic to avoid boxing.

Comment: `MemoryMappedViewAccessor` ultimately uses `SafeBuffer` which essentially does the same as the code that @Richard linked too.